# Apache2 cannot restart or start

Tags: apache, ubuntu, apache2, ubuntu-18.04

Well I have installed apache2 on my Ubuntu VPS and it has been running fine for quite awhile until recently, the website went down, I diagnosed the system and it seems apache stopped running.
I have enabled Apache in the firewall, tried restarting but they all didn't work.
This is the error I get after trying to restart apache with `systemctl restart apache2`

```
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

After running `systemctl status apache2.service` and `journalctl -xe`
This is the error

```
   Failed to dump process list, ignoring: Input/output error
* apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           `-apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2019-03-19 14:20:46 UTC; 6s ago
  Process: 53591 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/apachectl stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 48202 ExecReload=/usr/sbin/apachectl graceful (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 54521 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 386866)
   CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service

Mar 19 14:20:46 Mewbot systemd[54521]: Failed to attach 54521 to compat systemd cgroup /system.slice/apache2.service: No such file or directory
Mar 19 14:20:46 Mewbot apachectl[54521]: Action 'start' failed.
Mar 19 14:20:46 Mewbot apachectl[54521]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Mar 19 14:20:46 Mewbot systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Mar 19 14:20:46 Mewbot systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed to kill control group /system.slice/apache2.service, ignoring: Input/output error
Mar 19 14:20:46 Mewbot systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed to kill control group /system.slice/apache2.service, ignoring: Input/output error
Mar 19 14:20:46 Mewbot systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed to kill control group /system.slice/apache2.service, ignoring: Input/output error
Mar 19 14:20:46 Mewbot systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed to kill control group /system.slice/apache2.service, ignoring: Input/output error
Mar 19 14:20:46 Mewbot systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 19 14:20:46 Mewbot systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

Comment: Try to create the directory /system.slice/apache2.service.

Comment: I have tried that but it still pops the same error.

Comment: Maybe the directory is not writeable. chmod -R 777 /system.slice/apache2.service